# How to make Swagger 3 UI display example date in DDMMYYYY format?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a Spring Boot app with REST API, and in one of the request object, I declared a field which is supposed to hold a date in the format DDMMYYYY:

```
@Parameter(required = true, example = "20022022")
@Schema(required = true, type = "date", format = "ddmmyyyy", example = "20022022")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "ddMMyyyy")a
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@NotNull
private LocalDate valueDate;
```

In the Swagger UI, the example value of this field in the request body is always shown as below (current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD).

```
{
    ...
    "valueDate": "2022-03-17"
}
```

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I make the Swagger UI display the example date in the format DDMMYYYY? As you can see in my codes above, I put in @Parameter and @Schema but I really don't know how they work.

Comment: did you find solution to this?  also using Swagger 3 and I tried @Schema but that did not work

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the format.
The format is only valid if we use the English format. if we want to use dd/mm/yyyy we can't put format in the annotation.
for this reason we must use the annotation without the format and it has worked for me using localDate

```
@Schema(type = "string", pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy", example = "17-02-2020")
private LocalDate fecha;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).